# How to find the earliest date of the occurrence of a value for each year

Tags: oracle, date, max, partitioning

I have a table with this structure:

| STATION ID | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | RECDATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1950 | 01 | 01 | 01-01-1950 | 95 |
| 123456 | 1950 | 01 | 15 | 01-15-1950 | 85 |
| 123456 | 1950 | 03 | 15 | 03-15-1950 | 95 |
| 123456 | 1951 | 01 | 02 | 01-02-1951 | 35 |
| 123456 | 1951 | 01 | 10 | 01-10-1951 | 35 |
| 123456 | 1952 | 02 | 12 | 02-12-1952 | 80 |
| 123456 | 1952 | 02 | 13 | 02-13-1952 | 80 |

And so on.  There's a TMIN value for this station ID for every day of every year between 1888 and 2022.  What I'm trying to figure out is a query that will give me the earliest date in each year that a value between -100 and 100 occurs.

The query

```
select year, max(value) from table where value between -100 and 100 group by year order by year
```

gives the year and value.  The query

```
select recdate, min(value) from table group by recdate order by recdate
```

gives me every recdate with the value.

I have a vague memory of a query that practically partitions the data by a year or a date range so that the query would look at all the 1950 dates and give the earliest date for the value, then all the 1951 dates, and so on.  Does anyone remember queries like that?

Thanks for any and all suggestions.

Comment: I see I didn't phrase my question very well; I'll try again.

Comment: I completely messed up my question and would delete it, but Littlefoot took the time to help, so rather than delete it I'll restate it.

This is data from a NOAA temperature data set, and what I'm trying to get is the first light freeze of each year.  Littlefoot's query gives me the correct earliest date in each year, but what I want is the earliest date after summer.

It turns out all I have to do is add "and month > 8" to the query and I get what I want.  I'll give Littlefoot the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is your question:

> What I'm trying to figure out is a query that will give me the earliest date in each year that a value between -100 and 100 occurs.

Then you posted 2 queries which return *something*, but I don't see relation to the question. What was their purpose? To me, they look like some *random* queries one could write against data in that table.

Therefore, back to the question: isn't that just

```
select min(recdate),                 --> "earliest date
       year                          -->  in each year
from that_table                      --   that a   
where value between -100 and 100     -->  value between -100 and 100 occurs"
group by year
```